# disable gpu on android

Tags: android, gpu

I run cuda on a Nvidia Shield Tablet and my programm uses 100% the gpu, so the gpu cant render the screen, freezes(or it renders it very very slow) and closes my programm after a little. The thing is that I want to disable the gpu from rendering to the screen at all. Is there a way to do it in Android?

Thank you!
P.S: My programm is designed to consume 100% of the gpu so there is no problem with that